# NiFi: LDAP Authentication Multiple DN Issue

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi

### I Installed nifi-1.13.2

and I need to authenticate with LDAP
but there is some issue

when I want to use multiple account in different "OU"
I get this error

#### "Unable to validate the supplied credentials. Please contact the system administrator."

this is my login-identity-providers.xml:
[login-identity-providers.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KNrr.png)

this is my LDAP Server table:
[LDAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KswYX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I found The Solution

you should change ldap port to `3268`

like this

```
<property name="Url">ldap://10.1.21.2:3268</property> 
<property name="User Search Base">DC=COM</property>
```

this port is for Global catalog and mostly use for authentication